# Checking Multiple condition in case statement using MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx

How to write the below case statement in mdx.I moved the below mentioned columns in the fact table.

```
   sum(case when IsSummary = 1 and IsAudited  = 1 and FinalAuditFlag = 1 then 1 
else 0 end) AuditsCompleted,--Count - Completed Audits
```

i tried the below MDX query.

```
WITH 

    MEMBER [Measures].[count]
    AS
    (
     case  ([Measures].currentmember )
            when 0 then ([Measures].[Is Summary] )
                    else 1 
            end 
        )
    Select 
            {[Measures].[count]}    on 0,
            [Dim_table1].[TableId].members  on 1
    from    [Dsv]
```

Comment: This `[Measures].CURRENTMEMBER ` is referring to itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is almost correct. Just change `.currentmember` to an actual measure in your cube. Currently when you have the following it is referring to itself i.e. `currentmember` by the black arrow it referring to the measure `count` by the black arrow...

[image]

This is in `AdvWrks`:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} ON 0
 ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns this:

[image]

If I want to replace the empty cell for Components the we can use `CASE`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[count] AS  
     CASE  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        WHEN 0 THEN "XXX"             
          ELSE [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] 
      END  ,format_string = "#,###,##0"
SELECT 
  {
   [Measures].[count]
  } ON 0
 ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This now returns this:

[image]

`IIF` is used a lot more in `MDX` than `CASE` - `IIF` is nearly always faster. So the above equivalent using `IIF` is the following:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[count] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = 0
     ,"XXX"
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
   ,format_string = "#,###,##0" 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[count]} ON 0
 ,{[Product].[Product Categories].[Category]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your requirement is to find the sum over all the members of `[Dim Table1].[TableID]` hierarchy.

*If* so, then the below should work for you:-

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Count] AS
SUM(
    [Dim_table1].[TableId].CHILDREN, 
    [Measures].[Is Summary] * [Measures].[Is Audited] * [Measures].[Final Audited Flag] //If any is 0, it's 0, else 1
   )

SELECT Measures.[Count]
FROM [Dsv]
```

Let me know if further slicers are needed to be added or if my understanding is incorrect.